# Next.js rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js, netlify, fouc

I've built [my website](https://finnianlangham.com/) in Next.js, deployed statically via Netlify. Whenever I load it in a new tab, I get a white flash where the SVG logos are visible but nothing else, before the rest of the content loads in. I don't think this is a Flash Of Unstyled Content but it has a similar effect. I'm experiencing on desktop Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but doesn't seen to be happening on mobile. I've been trouble shooting for hours and am no closer to solving. [Here's the repo](https://github.com/flangham/finnianlangham) if anyone wants to have a look. Any insights greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting directly from [styled-components' docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#nextjs):

> Basically you need to add a custom pages/_document.js (if you don't
> have one). Then copy the logic for styled-components to inject the
> server side rendered styles into the .
>
> Refer to our example in the Next.js repo for an up-to-date usage
> example.

When using `styled-components` with Next.js you need to do a little magic in the `_document.js`. There is a `with-styled-components` example in the Next.js' repository. Please see here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js